# Paginação e Pesquisa - SpringData com SQLServer2008

Tags: hibernate, paginação, spring-data, sql-server-2008, eclipse-link

Olá, estou com um problema na minha aplicação e queria ver se alguém aqui pode me auxiliar.

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema com **SpringBoot** (**SpringData**, etc..) em cima de uma base **SQLServer2008**. Devido a força maior, foi necessário a implementação de um `datatable` que permita a paginação, e o filtro em multiplas colunas (vide anexo).

[image: datatable-com-paginação]

O que ocorre é que, quanto estou em uma página que não seja a primeira, e pesquiso na coluna por um valor os dados são inconsistêntes, deixa eu explicar.

O que ocorre é que, devido a maneira que o filtro está sendo aplicado na consulta a base de dados, os valores que vierem filtrados em uma "página" diferente da atual (ex: 2) não são mostrados. Desenhando..:

Caso tenha um `dataset` tal qual:

- joão
- mário

Se eu estiver paginando meu `datatable` com tamanho 1, e for para a segunda página, onde será mostrado o resultado `mário` e filtrar por joão, não consigo obter o resultado, pois a `query` "supõe" que o resultado deverá estar na segunda página do `dataset`.

Espero que tenha sido claro o suficiente.. :D

De implementação, estou utilizando o **Pageable** e **Specification** do **SpringData**.
Códigos relevantes:

```java
public class UsuarioRestController {
    private final UsuarioService usuarioService;
    public Page<UsuarioListModel> listarUsuarios(@PageableDefault Pageable pageable, @Validated UsuarioSearchCriteria usuarioSearchCriteria) {
        return usuarioService.buscaPaginado(usuarioSearchCriteria, pageable)
                .map(UsuarioListModel::new);
    }
}

public class UsuarioService {
    private final UsuarioRepository repository;
    public Page<Usuario> buscaPaginado(UsuarioSearchCriteria criteria, Pageable pageable) {
        return repository.findAll(criteria.getSpecification(), pageable);
    }
}

public class UsuarioSearchCriteria {
    private Long codigo;
    private String nome;
    private Boolean habilitado;
    public Specification<Usuario> getSpecification() {
        return Specification
                .where(UsuarioSpecifications.codigo(codigo))
                .and(UsuarioSpecifications.nomeLike(nome))
                .and(UsuarioSpecifications.habilitado(habilitado));
    }
}

class UsuarioSpecifications {
    static Specification<Usuario> codigo(Long codigo) {
        if (codigo == null) return null;
        return (root, query, cb) -> cb.equal(root.get("codigo"), codigo);
    }

    static Specification<Usuario> nomeLike(String nome) {
        if (nome == null) return null;
        return (root, query, cb) -> cb.like(root.get("nome"), "%" + nome + "%");
    }

    static Specification<Usuario> habilitado(Boolean habilitado) {
        if (habilitado == null) return null;
        return (root, query, cb) -> cb.equal(root.get("habilitado"), habilitado);
    }
}

public interface UsuarioRepository extends JpaRepository<Usuario, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Usuario> {
    Optional<Usuario> findByCodigo(Long codigo);
    Boolean existsByCodigo(Long codigo);
}
```

Pontos importantes:

- Já testei tanto com `Hibernate` quanto com `Eclipselink`, o problema persiste.
- Sei que o `SQLServer2008` não possui um bom suporte a paginação (eg, offset),  e isto muito possívelmente é o meu problema.
- Não tenho a possibilidade de trocar de `SGBD` infelizmente.

De qualquer forma, se alguém tiver alguma ideia, ou saiba uma solução, por favor! :help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei uma solução para o problema (não sei se é o melhor, mas está funcionando).

Pensando sobre a questão da páginação, vi que se eu tivesse uma maneira de ignorar a página quando houvesse um uma consulta por algum dos filtros eu conseguiria retornar os dados corretos. Já que se o filtro é uma consulta global, a página é de pouca importância na verdade.

Para implementar uma correção que fosse válida para todos casos da aplicação, acabei utilizando AOP do Spring, para ter um aspecto que interceptasse todas as requisições aos métodos que são responsáveis pela query filtrada e paginada e alterasse seus paramêtros conforme a necessidade.

Segue implementação:

```java
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class PaginationWithSpecificationsAspect {

    @Around("execution(* br.com.company.wms.app..filterAndPage(*,*))")
    public Object paginationAspectBefore(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        final Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();

        SearchCriteria criteria = (SearchCriteria) args[0];
        Pageable pageable = (Pageable) args[1];

        if (!criteria.isEmpty()) {
            // Caso existe consulta nos filtros, continua como se estivesse na primeira página (o que ignora a 'paginação' na consulta)
            return joinPoint.proceed(new Object[]{criteria, pageable.first()});
        }

        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }

}
```

Também fiz com que os `@Services` que expõe paginação tenham o método `filterAndPage(SearchCriteria, Pageable)`.

Não acho necessário colocar o restante do código relacionado pois não tem nada fora do comum ou muito diferente do que foi exposto na pergunta exceto por algumas pequenas modificações para o funcionamento da lógica.